# ZXing.Net.Mobile crashes app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I'm using `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms` in my project. Tried both FreshMVVM and Prism.

**`ScannerXamlPage.xaml`**

```
<Grid>
    <zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="ScannerView"
        Result="{Binding ScanResult, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
        ScanResultCommand="{Binding ProcessBarcodeCommand}"
        IsScanning="{Binding IsScanning}"
        IsAnalyzing="{Binding IsAnalyzing}" />
    <zxing:ZXingDefaultOverlay x:Name="ScannerOverlay"
        TopText="Hold your phone up to the QR code"
        BottomText="Scanning will happen automatically"
        ShowFlashButton="True"/>
```

This causes `RuntimeException: getParameters failed` when navigating away from the page, then back to it. [Related Github issue.](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/728)

This workaround solves it for now:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    Content = null;
}
```

Comment: report the issue on the project site: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues

Comment: It’s already reported, I’m just checking if someone knows a workaround.